# Can I exclude/hide tables SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a large database, and recently had to re-structure a portion of it.  I created some new tables, but I am reluctant to drop the old ones in case I have broken something that I am not aware of yet.  Is there a way to hide these old tables so that they don't clutter up my lists, but yet I have them available to re-use if I need them?

Comment: Take a backup of the database, then drop the tables. Otherwise, are you really sure you've removed all dependencies on the old tables?

Comment: Well, that's kind of the point.  I *think* I've removed all the dependencies, and I will check this during the testing phase, but the old tables contain test data that I don't want to re-enter if I need to re-create the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > they don't clutter up my lists

I guess you are referring to the Object Explorer here. One way to handle is to put those tables in a separate schema something like Junk or any name you like.

ALTER SCHEMA Junk TRANSFER dbo.YourOldTableName

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx

The other drastic option is to deny SELECT permissions on those old tables to yourself and have a separate login to access them. I don't even like this option :-)

Comment: I hadn't thought of using a separate schema. That should do just fine. Denying Select permissions is pretty creative, but I think it's more trouble than it's worth.  Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, the new tables names doesn't clash with old ones because you have chosen different names and you don't want to see the original ones to be visible in the object explorer of Management Studio.

You can hide them using the system stored procedure sp_addextendedproperty:

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support', 
@value = <Hide? , int, 1>, 
@level0type = 'schema', 
@level0name = N'<Schema Name, sysname, dbo>',
@level1type = 'table', 
@level1name = N'<Table Name, sysname, ?>'
```

This way only you (other don't see them) would still be able to query these tables when required.

http://avinashily.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-hide-table-in-sql-server.html